# How to use a different email address in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

The scenario we have is that we are storing email address information in other different data extensions. So it depends on the journey whether we use these or the primary email address (stored in all subscribers list). However, journey builder only uses the all subscribers list email address even if we set the Journey Builder Settings to > Use Primary Email Address from data extension; Use Email Address from Entry Source Only.

[image]

How do we make the journey use the email address stored in the data extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'The Use Email Address from Entry Source Only' option determines that Journey Builder will primarily use the address provided by the entry source.

If your email addresses are not in the entry source DE, then I'd suggest you define the Channel Address Order by:

1. Link to your Sendable DE containing the email addresses within an Attribute Group in Contact Builder (the DE will need to be sendable). You will need to create a 1:1 relationship back to the Contact record.
2. Open Contacts Configuration in Contact Builder.
3. Click 'Add Address' and select the email address field in the DE you linked to in Step 1.
4. Change the Channel Address Order as required.
5. Configure the journey to use the Channel Address Order in Journey Settings.

Comment: There is an Email Address field on the DE. But what happened was that the email still got sent to the Email Address on the all subscribers list. Any advise on how we'll be able to use the email address on the DE?

Comment: If you have configured the Email to use the Email Address field from your Event Source DE, then it will not update the All Subscribers list; your email will be sent to the email address in All Subscribers — this is the same behavior when using a Guided Send from a Sendable DE. **However**, if you use the Email Address from the Channel Address Order, then the email will be sent to that email address when the Contact reaches the Send Email Activity in the Journey and also update the Subscriber in All Subscribers list.